# How to make a raw SQL query to get the node/node_votes pairs?

Tags: 7, database

I'm not familiar with drupal. Using raw SQL, I'd like to extract votes given to each node, but I wonder how `vote_rating` is related to `node`?

I see that the votes are stored in `field_vote_rating` of this table:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE `field_data_field_vote`;
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entity_type       | varchar(128)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| bundle            | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted           | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id       | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| language          | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field_vote_rating | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| field_vote_target | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I'm aware of Drupal's database structure schema, which looks like so:

[image]

But I cannot figure out how to make a query to connect them.

**My question**: How to make a raw SQL query to get the node/node_votes pairs?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking about how the SQL should look like, or about some kind of tool/interface integrated with Drupal to write/run the SQL query you already have in mind? Maybe something else? Please EDIT your question to clarify that, OK?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens My question is about how to make a raw sql query to get the node/node_votes pairs. I've mentioned this in the first line but made it more explicit nonetheless.

Comment: I've tried to further refine your question (hope I did not introduce any errors in what you really want to ask). Please review and correct/enhance it where needed, OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT field_vote_rating from field_data_field_vote
WHERE entity_type = 'node' AND entity_id = $nid;
```

You can use the [database api](https://www.drupal.org/dynamic-queries) to create SQL Queries

Comment: This is not a valid sql query.

Comment: @Jand To be fair, anyone who's used PHP before will understand what that means. In case you're not in that group, it's a php variable which the op is using to indicate a placeholder for the proper variable. Replace that with the node id you're interested in, or remove that clause if you want to filter on all nodes